# How do I change the line spacing in Terminal?

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to change the line spacing in Terminal, or is there some other app that allows it?  I'm moving from the Mac, and its terminal app has this feature which allows line spacing to be changed independent of the font size.

E.g., here's Monaco on the Mac at 17pt, without any adjustments. My issue with it is that it's a jumble of text - the eye is drawn vertically as much as it is horizontally:

[image: Monaco]

And with "1.1" line spacing and slightly tighter character spacing. I do this so that my eye follows lines easier. It's a general rule of thumb in layout that space between lines should be larger than the space between words. This gets a little closer to that ideal:

[image: Monaco with my custom changes]

I'm wondering how to achieve this with Ubuntu. For now, my best workaround is to use Source Code Pro, which is designed with these ideas in mind, apparently:

[image: Source Code Pro]

Comment: Hi i am off to my PC now . but i am sure either from General or scrolling TAB in that window you can get that .

Comment: Not sure what your screenshot is supposed to accomplish or show; looks like a normal terminal screen to me.  Seems like you'd need at least two examples to show difference in line spacing, as different fonts have different spacing, depending on the height of the font.  But I think we all know what line spacing is, even though the terminal doesn't have that setting.

Comment: I updated the screenshots to better illustrate my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is one terminal emulator that has this feature.

```
urxvt
```

from man urxvt:

```
-lsp number
Compile frills: Lines (pixel height) to insert between each row of the display.      
Useful to work around font rendering problems; resource lineSpace.
```

urxvt is avalable in thease packages:

rxvt-unicode

rxvt-unicode-256color

rxvt-unicode-lite

Comment: Also `xterm` with the `scaleHeight` resource.

Answer (score 5):

This feature is available in `GNOME Terminal` version 3.28 (`VTE` terminal emulation library version 0.52).

Answer (score 4):

Konsole has this feature.  You'll find it under profile settings in the rightmost tab.  Konsole is a KDE application, but it has relatively few dependencies and seems to work well without KDE.

The mac terminal supports this for a good reason.  Atom (editor) supports it too.  To me it's indispensable.  I imagine, many people prefer a little more line spacing/ line height.

urxvt seems a little antiquated to me.

Comment: Only to increase line height though which is a shame. Doesn't allow you to tighten.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this is not directly achievable.  Nor would you want it to be. Having a space between lines would really mess up "text ui" based programs like nano, mail, and that little dialog that pops up when you run apt from the command line.

However, there is good news. You can just change the font.  Some fonts have a kind of "padding" that will give you the same effect.

I recommend that you use [Source Code Pro](http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html) it's very readable, though it honestly doesn't give as much padding as you want.

Keep in mind that on Linux the terminal is different concept then it is on OS X. As someone that is migrating myself, I think the best advice I can give is to just use the defaults for a while then make a decision.

Comment: Actually, I've ended up independently using half of your advice. First, I believe that it *is* desirable: I realize my screenshot may not clearly show it, but that's Monaco being displayed with a slightly larger line spacing. I find that it helps the text on the lines stick together more. But yes, Source Code Pro *does* space its lines further apart, and that's what I'm using on Linux.

Comment: You can also try out the font Ubuntu Mono.

Comment: @PaddyLandau Your comment gave me the idea for a different solution: hacking the TTF file to increase line height. I'll post an answer if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Tobia I look forward to it!

Comment: @PaddyLandau Frankly I don't have time to work on it, but I found a forum post that explains how it's done: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=22374

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a fix but you can add a blank line after every command with:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"
```

Comment: This will break a massive number of things. I don't suggest this. Plus this only works at the interpreter level (bash). The example above is command output, to address that you need to have line spacing on the emulator level.

Comment: If you want this, it's better to add a newline to `PS1`, for instance: `export PS1='\n$ '`.

Answer (score -1):

> space between lines should be larger than the space between words

I had the same requirement, and I use mobaxterm.
I do not want to use a new terminal just for such detail.
I find that just changing the font to `cascadia mono` or `source code pro` makes the screen enjoyable.

[mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWHKC.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1194862)

Comment: thanks, I think "changing the font to cascadia mono" is easier than change the terminal